# SQL Update update query error when updating with conditions of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have 3 tables with the following schema:

1. appointment(VAT_doctor,date_timestamp,description,VAT_client)
   VAT_doctor: FK(doctor)
   VAT_client: FK(client)
2. employee(VAT,name,birth_date,street,city,zip,IBAN,salary)
3. doctor(VAT,specialization,biography,e-mail)VAT: FK(employee)

And I want to make a SQL update query that Changes the salary of all doctors (doctors are a specialization of employees) that had more than 1 appointment in 2019. The new salaries should correspond to an increase in 5% from the old values.

I have already tried this in multiple ways, but an error always occurs (like  Operand should contain 1 column(s) )

```
UPDATE employee
SET salary = salary*1.05
where VAT in (
SELECT a.VAT_doctor, COUNT(a.VAT_doctor) AS count, e.VAT, e.salary
FROM appointment a

LEFT JOIN employee e on e.VAT = a.VAT_doctor


WHERE (EXTRACT(year from a.date_timestamp) IN ('2019'))
GROUP BY a.VAT_doctor
HAVING count > 1
);
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `join` in the `update` to do what you want:

```
update employee e join
       (select a.vat_doctor
        from appointment a
        where a.date_timestamp >= '2019-01-01' and
              a.date_timestamp < '2020-01-01'
        group by a.vat_doctor
        having count(*) >= 2  -- more than one appointment
       ) a
       on a.vat_doctor = e.vat 
    set salary = salary * 1.05;
```

I don't think the `doctors` table is needed, unless an appointment can have a `vat_doctor` reference to a non-doctor.